# Unity fade image alpha over time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm wanting to change the alpha of my UI Images gradually instead of instantly. So far my code for fading the alpha of my image instantly is as follows

```
public void Highlight()
{
    foreach (Image image in imagesToHighlight)
    {
        Color c = image.color;
        if(c.a < maxColor)
        {
            c.a = maxColor;
        }

        image.color = c;
    }

    foreach (Image image in imagesToFade)
    {
        Color c = image.color;
        if(c.a > halfColor)
        {
            c.a = halfColor;
        }
        image.color = c; 

    }

}
```

The above code works fine, but I'm struggling to modify my code so that instead of doing it instantly, it does it slowly over a second or two. I've tried changing the line `c.a = maxColor;` to `c.a--` in order to see if the image would continually fade out slowly but the alpha just instantly drops.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Coroutine` to implement this. Something like this:

**FadeOut:**

```
private YieldInstruction fadeInstruction = new YieldInstruction();
IEnumerator FadeOut(Image image)
{
    float elapsedTime = 0.0f;
    Color c = image.color;
    while (elapsedTime < fadeTime)
    {
        yield return fadeInstruction;
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime ;
        c.a = 1.0f - Mathf.Clamp01(elapsedTime / fadeTime);
        image.color = c;
    }
}
```

you may use it like this:

```
foreach (Image image in imagesToFade)
    StartCoroutine(FadeOut(image));
```

**FadeIn:**

```
IEnumerator FadeIn(Image image)
{
    float elapsedTime = 0.0f;
    Color c = image.color;
    while (elapsedTime < fadeTime)
    {
        yield return fadeInstruction;
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime ;
        c.a = Mathf.Clamp01(elapsedTime / fadeTime);
        image.color = c;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm not trying to modify it so that if the image is faded, it can go back to being full color. How could I do so?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a tween engine like Dotween and then simply use it like this :

`image.DOFade(1, 0.5f)`

Dotween has plenty of extention methods to help you, see the documentation.
http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php

`DOColor(Color to, float duration)
 DOFade(float to, float duration)`

Answer (score 0):

All credit goes to Umair M. All I have done is made it possible to use a single method rather than two. Also with no need to instantiate the method.

I have shown the whole class to indicate how to run the method without having consequential commands occurring before the Co-routine has finished.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class FishUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject mainPanel;
    public float fadeDelay = 1f;
        
    public void OpenPanel()
    {
        mainPanel.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine(Fade(mainPanel.GetComponent<Image>(), fadeDelay, true));
    }

    public void ClosePanel()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Fade(mainPanel.GetComponent<Image>(), fadeDelay, false));
        Invoke(nameof(DelayedSetActive), fadeDelay);
    }

    void DelayedSetActive()
    {
        mainPanel.SetActive(false);
    }

    IEnumerator Fade(Image image, float fadeTime, bool fadeIn)
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0.0f;
        Color c = image.color;
        while (elapsedTime < fadeTime)
        {
            yield return null;
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            if (fadeIn)
            {
                c.a = Mathf.Clamp01(elapsedTime / fadeTime);
            }
            else
            {
                c.a = 1f - Mathf.Clamp01(elapsedTime / fadeTime);
            }
            
            image.color = c;
        }
    }
}
```