# Fading back and fourth Unity Image alpha

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerable

I'm trying to create a way in which if I press a button, it'll highlight other objects whilst at the same time fading other objects. I also have other buttons that will fade and highlight different objects. Some of which may have been modified by the first button.

I had done this originally in a really dumb way like so

```
public void Highlight()
{
    foreach (Image image in imagesToHighlight)
    {
        Color c = image.color;
        if(c.a < maxColor)
        {
            c.a = maxColor;
        }

        image.color = c;
    }

    foreach (Image image in imagesToFade)
    {
        Color c = image.color;
        if(c.a > halfColor)
        {
            c.a = halfColor;
        }
        image.color = c; 
    }
}
```

This works, but I was wanting it to happen gradually to provide a smother transition. I managed to get the fade working, by changing the code to this:

```
IEnumerator Fade(Image image)
{
    float elapsedTime = 0.0f;
    Color c = image.color;
    while (elapsedTime < 1)
    {
        yield return fadeInstruction;
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        c.a = 1.0f - Mathf.Clamp01 (elapsedTime / fadeTime);
        image.color = c;
    }
}
```

I then call the method in my foreach loop like so:

```
foreach (Image image in imagesToFade)
{
    StartCoroutine (Fade (image));
}
```

Again, this works fine. The problem I'm having is checking to see if the image is faded, and if it is and needs to be highlighted, it reverses from the fade value to the highlight value (0.5 to 1.0).

I thought this would be a simple change as did this

```
IEnumerator HighLight(Image image)
{
    float elapsedTime = 0.0f;
    Color c = image.color;


    while (elapsedTime < 1 )
    {
        yield return fadeInstruction;
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

        c.a +=  Mathf.Clamp01 (elapsedTime / fadeTime);

        image.color = c;
    }
}
```

Simply changing the alpha line. However, now my image alphas jump all of the place in the highlight method. I'm at a loss as to how I can fix this. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you "yield return fadeInstruction" just after the while?

Comment: Why don't you check my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39849350/4366237) to your colleagues question.

Comment: How about 'while image.color.a > 0' or vice versa instead of elapsed time?

Answer (score 0):

StartCoroutine runs once if called in Update function. Are you calling the foreach loop  in the Update function? If so then update is calling foreach every frame and hence the looping the loops, possibly why the alphas are jumping all over the place